# Pattern matching & simple replacement

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, symbolic

I have a question about an expression that I want to modify.
Here is the expression:

```
-(((cA - 2 cF) (-cF (1 + x) log[1 - x] + 
        cF (-(1/3) π^2 delta[1 - x] + plusd[(2 Log[1 - x])/(1 - x)])))/(2 cF)) + 
 1/2 cA (delta[
      1 - x] (1/2 (-3 + mgl^2/(mgl^2 + sa1)) + (mgl^2 Log[mgl^2/(mgl^2 + sa1)])/
        sa1) + (3/2 cF delta[
         1 - x] ((2 mgl)/(mgl + Sqrt[mgl^2 + sa1]) + 
          Log[(2 mgl^2 + sa1 - 2 mgl Sqrt[mgl^2 + sa1])/sa1]) - 
       cF (1 + x) Log[(sa1 (1 - x))/(mgl^2 + sa1 (1 - x))])/
     cF + (2 Log[2 - x])/(-1 + x) + 
    2 Log[(sa1 (-2 + x))/(-mgl^2 + sa1 (-2 + x))] plusd[1/(1 - x)] + 
    Log[2 + mgl^2/sa1 - x] plusd[-(2/(-1 + x))] + 2 plusd[Log[1 - x]/(1 - x)] + 
    plusd[-((sa1^2 (-1 + x))/(2 (mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 x)^2)) + (2 (1 + 
           Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x]))/(-1 + x)]) + 
 1/2 (cA - 2 cF) (-cF (5 - π^2) delta[1 - x] + 
    cF (1 - x - (1 + x) Log[(1 - x)/x] + plusd[(2 Log[(1 - x)/x])/(1 - x)]))
```

hm, looks a bit weird but I am new to this forum and don't know how to format that expression in a proper way :D.

So, now I want to collect some terms. I have a function, called `plusd[]`. The function has different arguments including `x` and the function is multiplied by a sequence of other expressions.

What I want is to replace `x` with `1` in each factor that is multiplied by that function, not in the function argument itself and not in the part not multiplied by the function. The other part, which is not multiplied by that function I want to set to zero.

I guess it is easy with some pattern matching stuff but my skills are not good enough so I am asking here for help.

I am glad for any advice and of course also how to post my formulas in a nicer way.

Cheers and best regards,

Marcel

Answer (score 3):

seems to work:

```
expr /. Times[xx_?(! FreeQ[#, x] &) , p_plusd, rest___] :> Times[xx /. x -> 1, p, rest]
```

and terms like:

`2 Log[(sa1 (-2 + x))/(-mgl^2 + sa1 (-2 + x))] plusd[1/(1 - x)]` and

`Log[2 + mgl^2/sa1 - x] plusd[-(2/(-1 + x))]`

were reduced to

`2 Log[-(sa1/(-mgl^2 - sa1))] plusd[1/(1 - x)]` and

`Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1] plusd[-(2/(-1 + x))]`

---

> [...] The other part, which is not multiplied by that function I want to set to zero. [...]

The expression is partially collected so let's expand it before:

```
Map[
  If[
    FreeQ[#, _plusd], 
    0, 
    # /. Times[xx_?(! FreeQ[#, x] &), p_plusd, rest___] :> Times[xx /. x -> 1, p, rest]
  ]&
  ,
  ExpandAll[expr]
]
```

> ```
> cA Log[-(sa1/(-mgl^2-sa1))] plusd[1/(1-x)] +
> 1/2 cA Log[1+mgl^2/sa1] plusd[-(2/(-1+x))] +
> 1/2 cA cF plusd[(2 Log[-1+1/x])/(1-x)] +
> -cF^2 plusd[(2 Log[-1+1/x])/(1-x)] +
> cA plusd[Log[1-x]/(1-x)] +
> -(1/2) cA plusd[(2 Log[1-x])/(1-x)] +
> cF plusd[(2 Log[1-x])/(1-x)] +
> 1/2 cA plusd[2/(-1+x)+sa1^2/(2 mgl^4+4 mgl^2 sa1+2 sa1^2-4 mgl^2 sa1 x-4 sa1^2 x+2 sa1^2 x^2)-(sa1^2 x)/(2 mgl^4+4 mgl^2 sa1+2 sa1^2-4 mgl^2 sa1 x-4 sa1^2 x+2 sa1^2 x^2)+(2 Log[1+mgl^2/sa1-x])/(-1+x)]
> ```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Yes, it works. But can you explain the code a bit more. For pattern matching the only thing I know is sth like `x__` and `x_` :D. And the code does not neglect all the other factors which are not multiplied by `plusd[]`. Or better it does neglect them, but I wanna set them to zero :D. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Marcel Currently each term has `plusd` inside. What is term in your question then? Do you want to `ExpandAll`? About pattern matching, take a look at `PatternTest` and `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: ah, you are right. I wanna expand, yes:D. That I only have a sum of terms. So, expanding the expression beforehand will work, right? I will test :). Thanks a lot :D

Comment: hm, now I have all the terms expanded, but those terms are still in the expression after your replacement rule.

Comment: hm, I copied the code and replace expr with my expression. What I got now is th. like that `0[1/2 cA plusd[
   2/(-1 + x) + sa1^2/(
    2 mgl^4 + 4 mgl^2 sa1 + 2 sa1^2 - 4 mgl^2 sa1 x - 4 sa1^2 x + 
     2 sa1^2 x^2) - (sa1^2 x)/(
    2 mgl^4 + 4 mgl^2 sa1 + 2 sa1^2 - 4 mgl^2 sa1 x - 4 sa1^2 x + 
     2 sa1^2 x^2) + (2 Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x])/(-1 + x)]]` so, everywhere is now a zero as a factor. Sorry, I don't understand that much mathematica :)

Comment: @Marcel sorry, fixed typo.

Comment: yes it worked. perfect! Now How can I understand what you did:D I should do a tutorial on pattern matching, I guess :)

Comment: @Marcel Yes, feel free if anything is not clear then. :)

Comment: Nothing is clear:D I don't know all those mathematica commands:D like FreeQ, Map, Times, ... :D so far I only use mathematica to integrate and simplify stuff:D and simple replacements using `x_` and so on as patterns.

Comment: @Marcel Then definitelly I'm not going to explain this :D it would be endless. Put a cursor on a function and press F1 to lear more. Also: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html go there, take a look at thos functions and go through tutorial listed in LearningResources section.

Comment: yeah, I thought the same:D That wouldn't be worth it ^^. I will definitely try to understand what you did (at some point in time :D). Thanks for your advice and have a nice day!

Comment: @Marcel Thanks, good luck :)